# How to mimic regular Expression negative lookbehind?

Tags: regex, vba, negative-lookbehind

### What I'm trying to accomplish

I'm trying to create a function to use string interpolation within VBA. The issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how to replace "\n" with a `vbNewLine`, as long as it does not have the escape character "\" before it?

---

### What I have found and tried

VBScript does not have a negative look behind as far as I can research.

Below has two examples of Patterns that I have already tried:

```
Private Sub testingInjectFunction()
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    dict("test") = "Line"
    Debug.Print Inject("${test}1\n${test}2 & link: C:\\notes.txt", dict)
End Sub
```

```
Public Function Inject(ByVal source As String, dict As Scripting.Dictionary) As String
    Inject = source

    Dim regEx As Object
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regEx.Global = True

    ' PATTERN # 1 REPLACES ALL '\n'
    'regEx.Pattern = "\\n"

    ' PATTERN # 2 REPLACES EXTRA CHARACTER AS LONG AS IT IS NOT '\'
    regEx.Pattern = "[^\\]\\n"

    ' REGEX REPLACE
    Inject = regEx.Replace(Inject, vbNewLine)

    ' REPLACE ALL '${dICT.KEYS(index)}' WITH 'dICT.ITEMS(index)' VALUES
    Dim index As Integer
    For index = 0 To dict.Count - 1
        Inject = Replace(Inject, "${" & dict.Keys(index) & "}", dict.Items(index))
    Next index

End Function
```

---

**Desired result**

```
Line1
Line2 & link: C:\notes.txt
```

**Result for Pattern # 1: (Replaces when not wanted)**

```
Line1
Line2 & link: C:\
otes.txt
```

**Result for Pattern # 2: (Replaces the 1 in 'Line1')**

```
Line
Line2 & link: C:\\notes.txt
```

---

### Summary question

I can easily write code that doesn't use Regular Expressions that can achieve my desired goal but want to see if there is a way with Regular Expressions in VBA.

How can I use Regular Expressions in VBA to Replace "\n" with a vbNewLine, as long as it does not have the escape character "\" before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may use a regex here. Since the backslash is not used to escape itself in these strings, you may modify your solution like this:

```
regEx.Pattern = "(^|[^\\])\\n"
S = regEx.Replace(S, "$1" & vbNewLine)
```

It will match and capture any char but `\` before `\n` and then will put it back with the `$1` placeholder. As there is a chance that `\n` appears at the start of the string, `^` - the start of string anchor - is added as an alternative into the capturing group.

**Pattern details**

- `(^|[^\\])` - Capturing group 1: start of string (`^`) or (`|`) any char but a backslash (`[^\\]`)
- `\\` - a backslash
- `n` - a `n` char.

Comment: @Andreas I explained my regex and provided valid, tested, working VBA code. VBA does not allow escape sequences in its string literals. `"(^|[^\\])\\n"` "will be the text" ``(^|[^\\])\\n``.

Comment: Thank you for your help, works like a charm. Great explanation as well. I'm new to RegEx, so I learned a lot! Cheers!

Comment: Just noticed that doing `\n\n` only finds the first instance of `\n`. Is there a way to find them when they are back to back like this?

Comment: @RobertTodar What is the input string? `\n\n` cannot match one `\n`, it must match `\n\n`. And whether or not it finds the first or all occurrences, it is a job for `regexp.Global` property.  Please share a demo at http://regex101.com

Comment: @Andreas the string could be just about anything, using it for a string interpolation function I use. Should I just add white space between them? Here is an example: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZMX68L/1)

Comment: @RobertTodar I thought you would share a regex with a string sample :) Ok, if you need to remove all consecutive ``\n``s that start with a non-escaped ``\``, use `((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*)(?:\\n)+` pattern.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry :) I was wondering what you wanted an example of. That works though! I'll might have to take some time to try and understand what is happening in it though. At any rate, thank you!

Comment: It captures into Group 1 any char other than ``\`` or start of string, then 0 or more repetitions of double backslash, and then just matches 1 or more occurrences of ``\`` followed with `n`.